# IIS 10 - How to implement a rule that rewrites the path (...a bit...)

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

Using the IIS Application Request Routing, we will proxy requests to a preprod-server hosting services for both our dev, test, qa and stage environments. All this due to licenses issues of a 3'rd party software so we cannot have separate servers pr. environment. Therefore we will implement the "same" site/service on the preprod server with different ports and also names - prefix with the environment.

- MyServiceTest/mycode.svc
- MyServiceQA/mycode.svc
- MyServiceStage/mycode.svc

But, in addtion we also have different DNS-aliases pr environment, so what I plan is for clients of the service to access the environments like this

- myalias.test.mycorp.com/MyService/mycode.svc
- myalias.qa.mycorp.com/MyService/mycode.svc

Question is, how can I useing the URL Rewrite module create an action that adds the environment prefix to the first parth of the path, and then keeps the rest? The typical action routing to the serverfarm has the argument for passing on the path

```
/{R:0}
```

But as described above I need to "sneak" the environment to the first part of the pat. Is this doable?

Comment: The answer is of course yes if you improve your regular expressions.

Comment: Not entirely true since conditions does not use regex :-)

Comment: "conditions does not use regex" is wrong.

Comment: Well, it might be a variant of regex, but IIS at least is very clear on "Regular Expressions" vs. "Wildcards", so pardon my _french_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable regular expression for match URL, then it will works for condition pattern at the same time.

Please modify patternSyntax from wildcard to ECMAScript.
[image]

[image]

This rule will rewrite no matter QA TEST STAGE to backend MyServiceTest/*.

```
              <rule name="ARR_MyService-8052_lb" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myalias-test.mycorp.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/MyService(Test|QA|Stage)/(.*)" />
</conditions>
<serverVariables></serverVariables>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://myalias-test.mycorp.com-8052/MyServiceTest/{C:2}" />
  </rule>
```

If you want to map MyServiceTest to backend MyServiceTest and map MyServiceQA to backend MyServiceQA.

Then you could try this

```
  <rule name="ARR_MyService-8052_lb" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myalias-test.mycorp.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/MyService(Test|QA|Stage)/(.*)" />
</conditions>
<serverVariables></serverVariables>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://myalias-test.mycorp.com-8052/MyServiceTest{C:1}/{C:2}" />
  </rule>
```

Comment: My own answer did solve it for me, did some more tweaking in the script creating the farms, but this answer was what I was looking from the begining. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it, not entirely perfect, but at least a working solution. Reading the answer to the question  ["Capture the back-reference in the content URLs" posted on forums.iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/t/1187281.aspx) I realized that I could create capture groups even if the Conditions on IIS does not use regex. Each '*' will create a capture group, and then "hardcoding" the url (no issue since I script all rules) and adding {c:2}

```
<rule name="ARR_MyService-8052_lb" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myalias-test.mycorp.com" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/MyService*/*" />
</conditions>
<serverVariables></serverVariables>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://myalias-test.mycorp.com-8052/MyServiceTest/{C:2}" />
```

By not entirely perfect I mean that since it uses wildcard you can add whatever to /MyService/ and still the rule will work. But, for now I have only found that I can use wildcard in the conditions, so - well can live with that.